# Remove specific string from multidimensional array by value, not key

Tags: php

I need to remove Jackie Jackson from this array, I tried unset(I do not want to use key), array_diff, array_search. Nothing is working for me.

```
$employeeList= array(
        array(
            "ID" => "ID",
            "Name" => "Name",
            "Surname" => "Surname",
        ),
        array(
            "ID" => 1,
            "Name" => "John",
            "Surname" => "Smith",
        ),
        array(
            "ID" => 2,
            "Name" => "Jackie",
            "Surname" => "Jackson",
        ),   
        array(
            "ID" => 3,
            "Name" => "Chris",
            "Surname" => "Jones",
        ),  
        array(
            "ID" =>4,
            "Name" => "Amanda",
            "Surname" => "Cullen",
        ),   
        array(
            "ID" =>5,
            "Name" => "Jeremy",
            "Surname" => "Goodwin",
        ),  
    );
```

Comment: Write what you tried to solve your problem

Comment: I tried unset(I do not want use key), array_diff, array_search

Comment: `array_filter($arr, function($x) { return ! ($x[name] =='name' and ...)} );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array filter to check if the name and surname match. The string must contain name and surname separated by a space in this case so we can "explode" and pick up each individually. If name or surname do not exist in the "name_to_exclude" the function will simply return the original array.

```
$name_to_exclude = "Jackie Jackson";

$exclude = explode(' ', $name_to_exclude);
$employeeList = array_filter($employeeList, function($val) use ($exclude) { 
    if(array_key_exists(0, $exclude) && array_key_exists(1, $exclude)) {
        return $val['Name'] != $exclude[0] && $val['Surname'] != $exclude[1];
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to unset you can use the id of Jackie Jackson to match his key.

```
$id = 2;
unset($employeeList[array_search($id,array_column($employeeList, "ID"))]);
```

Have fun :)

Comment: thanks, but I would like delete by string not, using key, otherwise I just use unset($employeeList[2]); Still thanks reaching out

Comment: You can change "ID" by the thing you want to match